# Where to install plugins in Nexus 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

In Sonatype Nexus 2 plugins where installed in `sonatype-work/nexus/plugin-repository`

Such a folder is no longer available in Nexus 3. Is it still possible to install plugins in Nexus 3?

If it is still possible, where / how should plugins be installed?

I am btw trying to add support p2 Eclipse update site repository to my Nexus installed, see for example https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Nexus/article.html

I am looking for similar information for Nexus 3.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer via the Nexus web interface. On the start page it includes a link to https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-p2

The README has information on the various ways that the plugin can be installed.